# Angular 2 and web workers

Tags: angular, service, web-worker

How can angular 2 use web workers to run processes in the background? Is there any pattern I should follow on doing this?

I tried this:

```
npm i @angular/platform-webworker
npm i @angular/platform-webworker-dynamic
npm i @angular/platform-webworker
ng serve
```

into app.module.ts i add:

```
import {WorkerAppModule} from '@angular/platform-webworker';
//import {platformWorkerAppDynamic} from '@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic';
//import {ServiceMessageBrokerFactory, PRIMITIVE} from '@angular/platform-webworker';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    WorkerAppModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [CommentService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Angular 2 compiles correctly, but in http://localhost:4200/ i got this error:

zone.js:524 DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'.

I like use a service in backgroud

Comment: Also struggling with this.. take a look at [this link](https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135)

Comment: I read that certain browsers don't let you run web workers from localhost; it has to be from a valid domain . . .

Comment: Try to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:4200 instead of http://localhost:4200